# What is the correct way to punctuate direct questions that are not quotes?

Tags: questions, punctuation

What is the correct way to punctuate direct questions that are NOT quotes in a sentence in APA style?
Examples:

End of sentence:

> A lot of people wonder, How do judges get appointed?

or

> A lot of people wonder, how do judges get appointed?

or

> A lot of people wonder, "How do judges get appointed?"

Within a sentence:

> If you were wondering, How do judges get appointed? the answer is ....

or

> If you were wondering, how do judges get appointed? the answer is ....

or

> If you were wondering, "How do judges get appointed?" the answer is ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of quotes when wondering](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593653/use-of-quotes-when-wondering). See also Sven Yarg's comprehensive treatment at [comma/quote needed before 'quoted' material?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244544/comma-quote-needed-before-quoted-material/304508#304508) and [Is a comma needed after an italicized thought as it is with a prototypical quote?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/352621/is-a-comma-needed-after-an-italicized-thought-as-it-is-with-a-quote/352622#352622)

Comment: I'd use italics. A lot of people wonder: _How do judges get appointed?_

Answer (score 5):

Those "not-quotes" ***are*** quotes. You may not be quoting anyone specifically, but you are quoting a sentence someone might ask. Thus it needs to be punctuated as though someone had asked it.

> A lot of people wonder, "How do judges get appointed?" The answer is...

If you don't want quotation marks, you need to be more oblique.

> If you are wondering how judges get appointed, the answer is...
> A lot of people wonder how judges get appointed. The answer is...

Note that the last examples do not have *do.* It's the *do* which makes the first sentence a quotation because it actually forms a complete question.

It's very similar to [When asking readers to consider a question, what punctuation is needed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124288/)